# Does django caches function result in templates

Tags: python, django, templates, caching

I have in `models.py`:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()

    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()

    def get_stat(self):
        return {
            'xy': self.x + self.y,
            'ab': self.a + self.b
        }

    stat = property(get_stat)
```

In `team.html` I have:

```
xy stat: {{ team.stat.xy }}
ab stat: {{ team.stat.ab }}
```

The question is: "does django executes `get_stat` function everytime I call `stat` or it caches result?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `property` does not cache any results.

If you wanted it cached for heavy repeated access, the typical design pattern is:

```
def get_stat(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '__get_stat'):
         self.__get_stat =  {
            'xy': self.x + self.y,
            'ab': self.a + self.b
         }
    return self.__get_stat
```

Of course, this doesn't work if are doing something odd like dealing with instances that are modified in place, but not commited to the DB. I belive 99% of uses involve **DB->Object->Action**

Comment: @imkost, no problem, but integer addition isn't that expensive :D

Comment: @yuji-tomita-tomita, integer addition is just to make example easier to understand

Comment: @imkost, ah, roger that. Good example.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a specific answer as you have already learned that it is not cached, but some general advice. Usually, the way to determine if something like this is cached or not (or some random code is called) would be to add some logging or debugging statements in there.

```
def get_stat(self):
    # logging or debugging statement here, e.g. import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    # for ipdb, you need to pip install ipdb
    return {
        'xy': self.x + self.y,
        'ab': self.a + self.b
    }
```

You can also use this in django's own code to see the execution paths taken when your page is being served.